# Automated Unit Testing on Time based calculations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tdd

I have a small project which does some statistical calculations on the trades with inputs like Symbol, Price, time etc., I am using Visual Studio unit testing tools which is sufficient in case I do a normal testing of a class/function which does not go back/front in time.

I have certain statistical formulas to be calculated like for example a Moving Average. This may have to be calculated for 5 intervals based on a "1 minute" period. So I have to keep the last value of every minute (which I have put in logic) and do the averaging of the last value during the 5th minute.

The problem is now I lose 5 minutes for a single test to run (by putting Thread.Sleep). Is there an efficient approach to testing such Time based functions/algos?

Comment: roll forward time....

Comment: @MitchWheat, Doesn't it affect the system time if I roll forward?

Comment: Use an internal time; refactor to pass in a service that returns the current time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not just mocking/creating your test data with the appropriate Timestamp values e.g. `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1) 2 , 3 ,4...`...

Or does your business logic really have to wait one minute for each "iteration"? 
I mean, usually you just pass data to your calculation methods, regardless of the time the data has been created right?
If this is not the case, maybe refactor your code to be more testable ;)

Comment: This seems to be a neat idea. The code has to be refactored to be made more testable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use shims to specify the values you want returned for your timestamp values. Since you are using Visual Studio, check out this link to explain how to use them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx. Objects such as DateTime can be difficult to mock, because DateTime is a class and not an interface. The shim will redirect a call to an object, such as DateTime.Now to a custom function that you write.